# Is there a way to require Xcode Cloud workflow to pass for GitHub Pull Request to merge?

Tags: xcode, github, cicd, xcode-cloud

We are testing feasibility of migrating from GitHub Actions to Xcode Cloud for our CI/CD needs, and with GitHub Actions we could require that at least, say, the `build & test` workflow needed to succeed in order for a Pull Request to be merged, but I cannot find if that is possible with Xcode Cloud's integration. Xcode Cloud does show up in the PR's status checks, and it reports its success/failure status appropriately, but it does not prevent us from merging until the workflow has succeeded.

Xcode Cloud has a section where we can specify that the Test action is required to pass, but that seems to have no bearing on the PR itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using github branch protection rules:
[image]

Comment: thank you! as I am not an admin, I do not have access to this area, and didn't know it existed :-). got it added, thank you.